# Is it better to avoid DataFrames with MultiIndex when filtering?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

**Experiment 1: selection from DataFrame with default range index -**

```
In [167]: df_range = pd.read_csv('extract.csv')                                                      

In [168]: df_range                                                                                   
Out[168]: 
        frame  face  lmark   x   y
0           1   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1           2   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
2           3   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
3           4   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
4           5   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
...       ...   ...    ...  ..  ..
312809   5146   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312810   5147   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312811   5148   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312812   5149   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312813   5150   NaN    NaN NaN NaN

[312814 rows x 5 columns]
```

select index values excluding `frame` 5148 -

```
In [170]: ind = df_range.loc[(df_range['frame'] != 5148)].index.values                               

In [171]: ind                                                                                        
Out[171]: array([     0,      1,      2, ..., 312810, 312812, 312813])
```

select records from `df_range` excluding `frame` 5148 -

```
In [173]: df_range.loc[ind]                                                                          
Out[173]: 
        frame  face  lmark   x   y
0           1   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
1           2   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
2           3   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
3           4   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
4           5   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
...       ...   ...    ...  ..  ..
312808   5145   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312809   5146   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312810   5147   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312812   5149   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
312813   5150   NaN    NaN NaN NaN

[312813 rows x 5 columns]

In [174]: timeit df_range.loc[ind]                                                                   
14.1 ms ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Experiment 2: selection from DataFrame with MuitiIndex -**

```
In [177]: df_multi = pd.read_csv('extract.csv').set_index(['frame', 'face', 'lmark'])                

In [178]: df_multi                                                                                   
Out[178]: 
                   x   y
frame face lmark        
1     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
2     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
3     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
4     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
...               ..  ..
5146  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5147  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5148  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5149  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5150  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN

[312814 rows x 2 columns]
```

select frame values excluding `frame` 5148 -

```
In [215]: frames = df_range.loc[ind]['frame'].drop_duplicates().values                               

In [216]: frames                                                                                     
Out[216]: array([   1,    2,    3, ..., 5147, 5149, 5150])
```

select records from `df_multi` excluding `frame` 5148 -

```
In [218]: df_multi.loc[frames]                                                                       
Out[218]: 
                   x   y
frame face lmark        
1     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
2     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
3     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
4     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
...               ..  ..
5145  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5146  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5147  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5149  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5150  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN

[312813 rows x 2 columns]

In [219]: timeit df_multi.loc[frames]                                                                
7.83 s ± 607 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Conclusion**

Both methods select the correct result set but filtering a DataFrame with MultiIndex appears to be orders of magnitude slower than using the default range index. Do you agree?

**Update 13-03-2020** @ALollz - thanks for the inspiration. Here is a much faster way of filtering a DataFrame with MultiIndex -

```
In [40]: timeit df_multi.loc[df_multi.index.get_level_values('frame') != 5148]                       
4.53 ms ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [41]: df_multi.loc[df_multi.index.get_level_values('frame') != 5148]                              
Out[41]: 
                   x   y
frame face lmark        
1     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
2     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
3     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
4     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
...               ..  ..
5145  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5146  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5147  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5149  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
5150  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN

[312813 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

A MultiIndex has tuples as the indices. You switch to a MultiIndex but then still supply a single array of scalars as the Index, so pandas spends a lot of time trying to figure out exactly how to align those. If you instead supply the correct array of MultiIndex locs the speed is nearly the same (though maybe ~10x slower)

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(range(10**3))]*5, axis=1)
df.columns = range(5)

df_mult = df.copy().set_index([0,1], append=True)

ids = df[df[4].ne(4)].index
```

---

```
%timeit df.loc[ids]
#398 µs ± 5.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df_mult.loc[ids]
#121 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Use the correct MultiIndex locs
ids_mult = df_mult[df_mult[4].ne(4)].index

%timeit df_mult.loc[ids_mult]
#2.57 ms ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Though you might just slice by the Boolean Series, which tends to be very fast for most larger selections.

```
%timeit df_mult[df_mult[4].ne(4)]
#705 µs ± 5.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: you create `ids_mult` by filtering `df_mult` using a non-index column `[4]`. How would you efficiently filter `ids_mult` using an index column such as `[0]` of `[1]`?

Comment: @user2309803 you can use [`df.index.get_level_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html). That returns an array of the values of that level so you can filter it like normal, something like `df[df.index.get_level_values(0) != your_value]`